# Understanding the complement event of $\mathbb{P}[|X_n - X| < \epsilon] > 1 - \delta$, when $X_n$ converges to $X$ in probability

Tags: limits, probability-theory

I would like to verify whether my understanding of the the complement event of $E = \{|X_n - X| < \epsilon]\}, \mathbb{P}(E) > 1 - \delta$, i.e. $E^c =  \{|X_n - X| \geq \epsilon\}, \mathbb{P}(E^c) \leq \delta$, when $X_n$ converges to $X$ in probability, is correct. For the event $E$, given the $\epsilon, \delta > 0$ we know that there exists some $N \geq 1$ such that $\mathbb{P}[|X_n - X| < \epsilon] > 1 - \delta$ for all $n \geq N$. How I view this is that $X_n$ might fluctuate a lot from $X$ before the starting index $N$, and therefore the probability of $|X_n - X| < \epsilon$ might be smaller than or equal to $1 - \delta$ for all $n \leq N$. However, after the index $N$, we are $1 - \delta$ sure that all $X_n, n\geq N$ are at most within an $\epsilon$ away from $X$.

Then isn't the complement that for some $\epsilon > 0$ and $\delta > 0$ and for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists $n \geq N$ s.t. $\mathbb{P}(|X_n - X| \geq \epsilon) \leq \delta$? I.e. while almost all $n \geq N$ might satisfy that $|X_n - X| < \epsilon$, still we are $\delta$ sure that some (possibly only one) $X_n$ fluctuates at least as much as $\epsilon$ from $X$?

Comment: $E = \mathbb{P}[|X_n - X| < \epsilon]$ defines  a **number** $E$. So $E^{c}$ does not make sense.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks, the syntax is not fixed in the body text.

Comment: It is not clear at all what you are trying to ask. That $X_n$ converges in probability to $X$ means that the _probability_ of the events $|X_n - X| > \varepsilon$ tends to zero for all $\varepsilon > 0$ (the rate of convergence depends on $\varepsilon,$ of course). The $\omega$-by-$\omega$ behaviour of $X_n$ can be quite wild as there are known examples of $X_n \to X$ in probability and yet $X_n(\omega)$ _does not converge for any $\omega.$_